# iPhone App : Starting to play music very slow

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

Am working on an iPad/iPhone App & am playing a background music with this code snippet which I call in the Delegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method:

```
-(void) playMusic {
    NSLog(@"play music!");

    NSString *sound_file; 
    if ((sound_file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"musicfile" ofType:@"mp3"])){

        NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:sound_file];
        self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:NULL];
        self.audioPlayer.delegate = self;

        [self.audioPlayer setNumberOfLoops:-1]; // Infinite loop
        [self.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
        [self.audioPlayer setVolume:0.2];
        [self.audioPlayer play];

    } else {
        NSLog(@"WARN : music file not found!");
    }
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];

}
```

But I see that this method alone is taking 0.43 seconds on an average, which is a lot! Am I doing it the right way? Or is there a faster way to start the music play ? Please help.

My environment : iOS5, XCode 4.3, iPad 2.0 is what I tested this with now

Comment: There always seems to be a slight lag starting up AVAudioPlayer initially. What I would do is alloc/init the audio player in didFinishLaunching, and then start it in the viewDidAppear method in your initial view controller. This way the player will have time to load, and your user will hear the sound start the instant the initial view is presented.

Comment: NSPostWhenIdle , It is taking a bit lesser now (less by 0.1seconds) ; I have only AVAudioPlayer init code in the didFinishLauchingWithOptions , & I moved the actual play code to the viewDidAppear of the first page. However, this actual play code is now taking 0.3seconds ! Is there a way to make the 'start-playing' code quicker?